# Query to get children records of a parent

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have following table.

```
+-------+--------+-------+
|     Id|    Name| Parent|
+-------+--------+-------+
|      0|       A|     -1|
|      1|       B|      0|
|      2|       C|      1|
|      3|       D|      2|
|      4|       E|      2|
|      5|       F|      2|
|      6|       G|      2|
|      7|       H|      2|
|      8|       I|      2|
+-------+--------+-------+
```

`-1` as parent means it has no parent. The hierarchy can go upto 7-8 levels.
I need to get all the children (direct + indirect). I tried something like:

```
SELECT Id, NAME, @pv:=Id AS 'Parent' FROM tbl
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=-1)tmp
WHERE Parent=@pv
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?>

Comment: @TheProvost, list of all the children i.e. for `A`, I expect records `B` to `I`. Since B is child of A. C is child of B and rest are children of C.

Comment: oh then i suggest you use CTE. its like a subquery but you can call it recursively which is exactly what you need.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: @TheProvost: MySQL does not support recursive queries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh sorry i did not know that. Well  you can always create a stored procedure and call itself recursively

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2
FROM tbl1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl1 AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 2;
```

expected output

```
+-------+--------+
|   lev1|    lev2|
+-------+--------+
|      C|       D|
|      C|       E|
|      C|       F|
|      C|       G|
|      C|       H|
|      C|       I|
+-------+--------+
```

[Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)